# GTEST: False negative for incorrect number of macro arguments

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a class `A` for which I've overloaded the `operator[]` such that if object `a` of class `A` can have an [std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) passed to it in the following manner:

```
 std::valarray<int> in{2,1};
 auto b = a[in]; // lets say this returns an int k = 2
 auto c = a[{2,1}]; // also returns an int k = 2
```

However, when using the GTEST framework, it doesn't like the `a[{2,1}]` notation, and complains that `macro "EXPECT_EQ" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2` if we are to try a test such as `EXPECT_EQ(2, a[{2,1}]);`

Surely `a[{2,1}]` is a single argument, since it evaluates to an `int`?  This doesn't seem to be the case.  A typical `EXPECT_EQ` such as `EXPECT_EQ(2, 2);` is just fine.

Below, I have a MWE of a class that overloads `[]` to takes a parameter of type `std::valarray`.

```
class A
{
private:
    std::vector<int> elems;
public:
    A(std::vector<int> elems)
    : elems(elems){};

    int operator[](std::valarray<int> idx) const 
    {
        return get_elem(idx[0]);
    }; // getter

    int get_elem(int idx) const {return this->elems[idx];}; //getter
    int &get_elem(int idx) {return this->elems[idx];}; //setter

  }; 

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> elems = {2, 5, 0, 9,
                              5, 1, 4, 6};

    A a(elems);
    std::cout<< "hello world" << std::endl;

    std::valarray<int> in{2,1};
    auto b = a[in]; // lets say this returns an int k = 2
    auto c = a[{2,1}]; // also returns an int k = 2
    std::cout<< b << std::endl;
    std::cout<< c << std::endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Given that my `main()` displays correct behaviour, I suspect that there is an issue with `GTEST`, or is evaluation order in C++ different from what I expect?

Comment: Macros have very limited understanding of C (let alone C++) syntax. Your argument has a coma in it, so it's two arguments. Doesn't gtest provide normal (non-macro) alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since macros are involved, and there is no getting rid of them, the quickest solution is a judicious use of parentheses:

```
EXPECT_EQ(2, ( a[{2,1}] ));
```

The extra pair will prevent the comma from being interpreted as an argument separator for the macro. As for the comparison itself, a parenthesized expression has the exact same value and value-category as the expression withing the parentheses. So everything should still work<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Unless Google Test applies `decltype` to that second sequence of tokens, then the extra parentheses can potentially cause surprises. But it shouldn't be doing that.</sub>

Comment: yes, can confirm that it works.  Thank you.  Since this is something that should only cause problems in tests, my purposes don't need to dig further into the problem.  Any thoughts on why though I hope would be useful to any future readers